# How to use the parameterization to find volume of ellipsoid?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

If I have the ellipse in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to be defined as $x^2+4y^2=1$ with the parameterization $\gamma: \mathbb{R}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined as $\gamma(t)=cos(t),4sin(t)$ how would I set up an integral to solve for the volume of my ellipsoid?

Comment: Note that "ellipsoid" and "volume" refer to three dimensions, but you have only two dimensions in $\mathbb R^2.$

Comment: it is very possible that I set up the parameterization wrong? Do you think that is the problem?

Comment: Yes, the parameterization appears to be incorrect. You can use the first equation to find out what $y$ should be when $x$ is zero and what $x$ should be when $y$ is zero.

Comment: I don't understand. They would both be $=1$

Comment: What happens when you put those values of $x$ and $y$ into the equation $x^2+4y^2=1$? It is true that $1^2+4(0^2)=1,$ all right, but is it also true that $0^2+4(1^2)=1$?